# Numerical Column for Vaadin-Grid does not sort by number

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a data result set taken from a database and I am populating it in a Grid. Although I have managed to populate the grid with data, sorting a numerical value column sorts the values in string text form.

For example:

```
15
24
26
4
63
9
```

My dataset in a form of the LinkedHashedmap<String,String>. I have managed to get it populated, and I had a secondary private method acting as to determine if the value is a numerical format or not.

This is the main code fragment that is used to populate the grid:

```
        int i=0;
        boolean exeflg = false;
        String captn;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : s.entrySet()) {
            if (gridShowCol == null || gridShowCol[i] > 0) {
                if (gridcolName!=null) 
                    captn= gridcolName[i];
                else captn = entry.getKey();
                if (gridcolAllign!= null) {
                    if (gridcolAllign[i]==1 || gridcolAllign[i]==3) -- If column type is a number or decimal
                        grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setCaption(captn).setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-left");
                    else
                        grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setCaption(captn).setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-right");
                } else {
                    if (i==0 || !isNumeric(entry.getValue().toString())) -- This is for the header column
                        grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setCaption(captn).setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-left");
                    else { 
                        grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setCaption(captn).setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-right");
                    }
                }
                                    
                if (!exeflg && gridSelectCol != "") {
                    // Disable selection: will receive only click events instead
                    grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.NONE);
                    exeflg = true;
                    grid.addItemClickListener(
                        event -> {
                           gridCliickResp(event.getItem());
                    });
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Secondary helper method:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if (strNum == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is said that setRenderer does not work for Grid<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>, so is there an alternative to have that column sort by number?

Comment: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17789834/grid-sort-column-with-renderer ?

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Solution

You are creating a column with a String value, so maybe using the parsed double as the column value would be enough. This way probably the natural order of the Double is used.

## 2. Solution

If not, use `grid.setComparator()`
https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.5.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/Grid.Column.html#setComparator-java.util.Comparator- like this:

```java
import static java.lang.Double.parseDouble;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingDouble;

column.setComparator(comparingDouble(h -> parseDouble(h.get(entry.getKey()))));
```

Comment: Looks like solution #1 would be the fit because the setComparator in #2 below does not work for Vaadin 8. But I could not find an example of setting a NumberRenderer for the non-Bean using LinkedHashmap<String,String>. Any example that I can see that can match the requirement?